# Adb force real touch

Tags: python, adb, android-uiautomator, gesture-recognition

Im writing python testcases for a payment terminal operating on android.
I know how to use UIAutomator2 and adb tap or keyevent but im facing an issue. I cant interact with any of the buttons only on the payment app pin-pad. What it looks like to me the programmers  put a safeguard in place that prevents any source of interaction other than the physical touchscreen. Is there a way to force adb to emulate a real touch instead of removing the safeguard? This is important for testcase automation and because i work on a remote machine with the terminal plugged into it. Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example it would be very difficult to help you without that

Comment: I know but i dont have access to the app code, all im looking for is a way to force adb to use the actual touchpad ports when sending instructions to the terminal

Answer (score 0):

You can try this and check if the **long click** works in your case.

I'm using **Calculator** and a long click on the **AC** button.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Copyright (C) 2013-2022  Diego Torres Milano
Created on 2022-05-24 by Culebra v21.4.2
                      __    __    __    __
                     /  \  /  \  /  \  /  \ 
____________________/  __\/  __\/  __\/  __\_____________________________
___________________/  /__/  /__/  /__/  /________________________________
                   | / \   / \   / \   / \   \___
                   |/   \_/   \_/   \_/   \    o \ 
                                           \_____/--<
@author: Diego Torres Milano
@author: Jennifer E. Swofford (ascii art snake)
"""


from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient, KEY_EVENT


device, serialno = ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit()

kwargs2 = {'useuiautomatorhelper': True}
vc = ViewClient(device, serialno, **kwargs2)

obj_ref = vc.uiAutomatorHelper.ui_device.find_object(body={'checkable': False,
     'clazz': 'android.widget.Button',
     'clickable': True,
     'depth': None,
     'desc': 'clear',
     'index': None,
     'instance': None,
     'pkg': 'com.google.android.calculator',
     'res': 'com.google.android.calculator:id/clr',
     'scrollable': None,
     'text': 'AC'})
vc.uiAutomatorHelper.ui_object2.long_click(oid=obj_ref.oid)
```

The script was generated using [culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki/culebra) from [AndroidViewClient](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki/culebra) using [CulebraTester2-public](https://github.com/dtmilano/CulebraTester2-public) backend.